# Delete the email after it is moved to the folder (Outlook rule)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter, rules

I have a rule that moves emails if it comes from a specific person. For instance, if an email arrives from rick@abc.com it moves the email to "Rick" folder.

Now, Rick also sends me some routine emails with data files in them. I created a rule (checks a sentence within the email body) to move those emails into "Data" folder.

But now I have duplicates. Outlook does move these "data" emails into its own folder ("Data") but I would like the originals in "Rick" folder to be deleted when the move operation is finished. How to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot the rules you have? Is your second rule looking at Inbox or the Rick folder?

Comment: I bet Hillary knows....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Move` operation means that the original copy won't be preserved.
I think you should create 2 rules like this:
rule 1: if the mail comes from rick and contains a certain sentence, then move it Data.  And stop processing more rules.
rule 2: if the mail comes from rick, then move it to folder Rick. And stop processing more rules.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you create David's rules in that sequence. In other words, more explicit, particular rules up top, containing the "stop processing more rules" (aka "that's it, you're done, stop acting on this message"), followed by more generalized rules that will only fire if the ones above fail to match on conditions.

E.g.

- rule that looks for messages from Rick, with one or more attachments, and body containing text "invitation" => move to Rick's Invites, stop processing rules; [Calendar invites from Rick, with or without other files attached.]
- rule that looks for messages from Rick, with one or more attachments => move to Data, stop processing rules; [Data files from Rick, but not Invites.]
- rule that looks for messages from Rick => move to Rick, stop processing rules. [Anything else from Rick.]